# Writing tips - on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, off-topic

If I post “what are your favorite writing tips” will it get shut down?

I know the answer is probably yes, but I thought it would be cool, since the upvotes would rank them best to worst, and it would be fun to have a list of awesome writing tips, and I was hoping other people would agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Writing SE!

Unfortunately I think you're correct in that this would be off-topic as a question looking for "general" tips would be too broad for the SE format. Really we need questions that have a narrower scope.

As the [help](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page puts it:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

That doesn't mean you can't gather awesome, writing tips, ranked by votes for their usefulness - because really the question that you propose is the *whole* site, with the "tips" helpfully categorized into specific areas of writing by the questions and their tags. This means that if you are looking for "tips" on say "How to overcome writers block?" You can do to the [tag page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers-block) for it and you'll get a list of the questions asked around it select a question that sounds most like your situation and get a selection of [answers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/dealing-with-writers-block) that are community ranked by their votes.

The ranking is then *more* useful to you because these are different solutions (or "tips") that are being directly compared with each other as to how well they solve the particular problem.

Comment: When I said “tips” I was saying more along the lines of quotes. I had found a couple lists of “writing tips from authors” and thought it would be cool to have everyone contribute ones they find. And with it all being organized best to worst, it seemed like it would be fun to have.

Comment: @Doragon Apologies.. I know what you mean now. Unfortunately that sort of thing doesn't really work in the SE Q&A format and would be off topic

Comment: Oh well. At least I’ll share a one good one here: “inspiration is for amateurs. The rest of us just show up and get to work “ - Chuck Close